# Android - How to simplify multiple of ten?

Tags: java, android, multiplication

I want to multiple values like this:

```
if (currentScore == 10 | currentScore == 20 | currentScore == 30 | currentScore == 40 | currentScore == 50 | currentScore == 60
            | currentScore == 70 | currentScore == 80 | currentScore == 90 | currentScore == 100 | currentScore == 110
            | currentScore == 120 | currentScore == 130 | currentScore == 140 | currentScore == 150 | currentScore == 160
            | currentScore == 170 | currentScore == 180 | currentScore == 190 | currentScore == 200) {
        editor.putInt("TOP_LEVEL", topLevel + 1);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

How to simplify that code so can count many currentScore.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Java `%` [operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html):

```
if (currentScore % 10 == 0) {
    editor.putInt("TOP_LEVEL", topLevel + 1);
    editor.apply();
}
```

The `%` operator returns a remainder. If the remainder of the division of "currentScore" by 10 is 0, this means that currentScore is an exact multiple of 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
int j = 10;

for (int i = 1; i <= 20 ; i++) {
     if (currentScore == j) {
         editor.putInt("TOP_LEVEL", topLevel + 1);
         editor.apply();
         break;
     }
     j = j + 10;
}
```

Comment: This will not work for any other number than currentScore being 10, e.g. if currentScore = 100, your program will not work. And even then, why are you printing 20 times?

Comment: I edited my answer, now it works fine :) thank you @vshcherbinin